# Form submission to iframe on different page and domain

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I'm attempting to fill a form out one page and use the results of that form to affect an iframe on another page. The iframe content is not on the same domain.

The form lives on **PAGE A** 
http://songbee.me/hosting/healthquotepro/

```
<form action="./quotes.html" target="quotes" method="POST" name="zips">
<input type="text" name="zip_code" placeholder="ZIP code" maxlength="5">
<button type="submit">See Plans</button>
</form>
```

I'm trying to get the form to fill out the 'Zip Code' area of this iframe on **PAGE B** http://songbee.me/hosting/healthquotepro/quotes.html

```
<iframe style='border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%' src='https://www.healthsherpa.com?_agent_id=scott-freeman'></iframe>
```

As it stands now, when the form is submitted there is no action.

Comment: what error does the console display?

Comment: where is your javascript?

Comment: Im using Wordpress for this site. Are you asking about the JS for the form?

Comment: the js for the transfer of the zip code to the iframe